# Create barplot from 2 count variables in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have 2 columns that I have summed up from an analysis and would like to use a barplot to compare them against each other but my code isn't working and I feel like its a dumb error. My columns simply have 1 or NA for values. So I summed them and want to take the 2 columns and compare. I can do the formatting of the graph, just getting it to display.

Code:

```
Keenum_total <- sum(Vikings_dataset$Keenum, na.rm = TRUE)

Bridgewater_total <- sum(Vikings_dataset$Bridgewater, na.rm = TRUE)

Quarterback_totals <- table(Keenum_total, Bridgewater_total)

barplot(Quarterback_totals)
```

Comment: what is your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `table()` line before making the barplot, since by summing each column you have aggregated them to the level they need to be at for `barplot()`.

Here's an example you can use with the (built-in) `iris` dataset:

```
sepal_length_total <- sum(iris$Sepal.Length, na.rm=TRUE)
sepal_width_total <- sum(iris$Sepal.Width, na.rm=TRUE)

barplot(c(sepal_length_total, sepal_width_total))
```

If you want to display the name by each bar, you can use a named vector inside of `barplot()`, as in:

```
barplot(c(sepal_length=sepal_length_total, sepal_width=sepal_width_total))
```

Comment: Perfect! I was missing the c()